# How to unwind `funcstack`?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

It's not a good idea to use `set -e` inside functions<sup>1</sup>, because it will cause one's shell to terminate on error.

Therefore, in shell functions a *lot* of my code looks like this:

```
[[ -e $file ]] || {
    printf -- 'foo: %s does not exist\n' $file >&2
    return -1
}
```

...which is not only bulky, but also ineffective beyond the first frame of `funcstack`.
It would be great if there were an `error` function that would allow at least to condense the code above to something like this

```
[[ -e $file ]] || error -1 '%s does not exist' $file
```

Writing such an error function for use in *interpreted* scripts (as opposed to functions) is not too difficult:

```
error () {
    local exitstatus=$1
    shift

    {
        printf -- '%s: ' "${funcstack[2]}"
        printf -- "$@"
        printf -- '\n'

    } >&2

    exit $exitstatus
}
```

...but calling this function from within other functions is a bad idea, for the same reason that `set -e` inside functions is a bad idea.

What's needed to implement the desired `error` function is a way to return control to the invoking shell's "top level" (thereby clearing `funcstack`, which could be arbitrarily long at the time `error` gets invoked).

Is there a way to do this?

---

PS: Of course, I did try the naive way to this:

```
error () {
    local exitstatus=$1
    shift

    {
        printf -- '%s: ' "${funcstack[2]}"
        printf -- "$@"
        printf -- '\n'
    } >&2

    funcstack=()
}
```

...but (unsurprisingly), `zsh` will have none of it:

```
error:10: read-only variable: funcstack
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In this post I'll use expressions like "from within a function" as shorthand for "from within shell functions intended for interactive use or from within scripts meant to be sourced".</sup>

Comment: How about `$funcstack[-1]`?

Comment: @cuonglm: I don't understand your suggestion.  *By itself* `$funcstack[-1]` will probably lead to an infinite recursion (if `$funcstack[-1]` is a function), or to a `permission denied` error (if `$funcstack[-1]` is a non-executable script that is being sourced).

Comment: I mean instead of `printf -- '%s: ' "${funcstack[2]}"`, you will do `printf -- '%s: ' "${funcstack[-1]}"`

Comment: @cuonglm: ah, sure, but that's a cosmetic issue.  The problem is how to unwind `funcstack`, and return control to the nearest invoking shell's "top level", i.e. to the level from where `$funcstack[-1]` was invoked.